# how to find the indices of a numpy array and print the corresponding row in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe and want to print elements of one list based on one columns of this dataframe. This is my dataframe:

```
data={'names':['Fa_1', 'Fa_2', 'Lay'], 'order':[1,2,3], 'Rel':['Fault', 'Fault', 'Ero']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And this is my list which contains some arrays:

```
ver=[[np.array([[1., 2., 3.]]), np.array([[2., 4., 6.]])],\
     [np.array([[2., 2., 2.]]), np.array([[5., 1., 4.]])],\
     [np.array([[3., 1., 6.]]), np.array([[8., 0., 2.]])],\
     [np.array([[6., 1., 2.]]), np.array([[1., 3., 1.]])]]
```

My `df` has three rows but my `ver` has four rows (lists) and this makes a problem for me. When the last column of `df` is `Fault`, I want to print the `max` of the arrays stored in the same list number of `ver`. If it is anything else, I want the `min`. Important point is that in my `rel` column of `df`, I have two `Fault`s and one `Ero` but I have four lists stored in `ver`. Each `Fault` has its own list (first and second lists in `ver`) but the `Ero` has the next the last two lists. At the moment my code is working fine or lists of `Fault` but for `Ero` it only shows the `min` of one row:

```
for rows in range (len(df)):
    if df.iloc[rows, -1]=='Fault':
        for lists in ver[rows]:
            print (np.max(lists))
    else:
        for lists in ver[rows]:
            print (np.min(lists))
```

This code ignores printing `min` of the last list stored in `ver`.
I do appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain in a clearer (one sentence) what is the desired outcome of your code? Thanks

Comment: Dear @Michael Sidorov, the outcome is max values of the first and second rows (lists) and mins of the third and last rows of y list named `ver`. current code does not include the last list.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is just replacing i by row:

```
for rows in range (len(df)):
if df.iloc[rows, -1]=='Fault':
    for lists in ver[rows]:
        print ("max",np.max(lists))
else:
    for lists in ver[rows]:
        print ("min",np.min(lists))
```

Comment: Dear @yasharov, your solution was solving a typo and I am looking for somethiung else.

Comment: So, If you find my solution as true, consider accepting it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I think indentations are not correct @yasharov

Comment: Dear @yasharov, I do appreciate your time but your solution does not solve mz main problem. I want to print min values of the last list stored in `ver`

Answer (score 0):

To do so, I found a possible way. After finding the max values of the first two lists, I do the second for loop for all the remaining lists in `ver`:

```
for rows in range (len(df)):
    if df.iloc[rows, -1]=='Fault':
        for lists in ver[rows]:
            print (np.max(lists))
    else:
        for lists in ver[rows:]:
            for m in lists:
                print (np.min(m))
```

I do appreciate if anyone else could give me more clever ways to do it.